# How to return the substring of a string between two strings in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

How would I return the string between two string markers of a string in Ruby?

For example I have:

- `input_string`
- `str1_markerstring`
- `str2_markerstring`

Want to do something like:

```
input_string.string_between_markers(str1_markerstring, str2_markerString)
```

Example text:

```
s
# => "Charges for the period 2012-01-28 00:00:00 to 2012-02-27 23:59:59:<br>\nAny Network Cap remaining: $366.550<br>International Cap remaining: $0.000"
str1_markerstring
# => "Charges for the period"
str2_markerstring
# => "Any Network Cap"
s[/#{str1_markerstring}(.*?)#{str2_markerstring}/, 1]
# => nil  # IE DIDN'T WORK IN THIS CASE
```

Using Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

```
input_string = "blahblahblahSTARTfoofoofooENDwowowowowo"
str1_markerstring = "START"
str2_markerstring = "END"

input_string[/#{str1_markerstring}(.*?)#{str2_markerstring}/m, 1]
#=> "foofoofoo"
```

or to put it in a method:

```
class String
  def string_between_markers marker1, marker2
    self[/#{Regexp.escape(marker1)}(.*?)#{Regexp.escape(marker2)}/m, 1]
  end
end

"blahblahblahSTARTfoofoofooENDwowowowowo".string_between_markers("START", "END")
#=> "foofoofoo"
```

Comment: As a general idea this is fine, but for the final implementation, one should use Regexp.escape on the markers.

Comment: oh, just noted this didn't work for my text - I've put my example text in the question above.  It's basically representative of the text I'll get back in a html <div>.

Comment: @Grep I edited my answer a while after my first post. The key is to **put the option `m` after the regex**. See the difference between my answer now and what you tried? This will make it match beyond a single line. Without it, it doesn't.

Comment: ar yes, this works excellent now - thanks for responding sawa

Comment: the `m` modifier enables multiline mode

Comment: what if you have multiple "START" "END"  in the string it will return the first match only. how to make it to work for all

Answer (score 20):

Just split it twice and get the string between the markers:

```
input_string.split("str1_markerstring").last.split("str2_markerstring").first
```

Comment: hells yeah, screw Regex if you can just split it

Answer (score 0):

Here's some alternate ways to do what you want, that are how I'd go about it:

```
s = "Charges for the period 2012-01-28 00:00:00 to 2012-02-27 23:59:59:<br>\nAny Network Cap remaining: $366.550<br>International Cap remaining: $0.000"  # => "Charges for the period 2012-01-28 00:00:00 to 2012-02-27 23:59:59:<br>\nAny Network Cap remaining: $366.550<br>International Cap remaining: $0.000"

dt1, dt2 = /period (\S+ \S+) to (\S+ \S+):/.match(s).captures  # => ["2012-01-28 00:00:00", "2012-02-27 23:59:59"]
dt1                                                            # => "2012-01-28 00:00:00"
dt2                                                            # => "2012-02-27 23:59:59"
```

This is using "period" and "to" and the trailing ":" to mark the begin and end of the range to be searched for, and grabbing the non-whitespace characters that signify the date and time in each datetime stamp.

Alternately, using "named-captures" predefines the variables:

```
/period (?<dt1>\S+ \S+) to (?<dt2>\S+ \S+):/ =~ s  # => 16
dt1                                                # => "2012-01-28 00:00:00"
dt2                                                # => "2012-02-27 23:59:59"
```

From that point, if you want to break down the values returned you could parse them as dates:

```
require 'date'
d1 = DateTime.strptime(dt1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  # => #<DateTime: 2012-01-28T00:00:00+00:00 ((2455955j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
d1.month                                          # => 1
d1.day                                            # => 28
```

Or you could even use sub-captures:

```
matches = /period (?<dt1>(?<date1>\S+) (?<time1>\S+)) to (?<dt2>(?<date2>\S+) (?<time2>\S+)):/.match(s)
matches # => #<MatchData "period 2012-01-28 00:00:00 to 2012-02-27 23:59:59:" dt1:"2012-01-28 00:00:00" date1:"2012-01-28" time1:"00:00:00" dt2:"2012-02-27 23:59:59" date2:"2012-02-27" time2:"23:59:59">
matches['dt1']   # => "2012-01-28 00:00:00"
matches['date1'] # => "2012-01-28"
matches['time2'] # => "23:59:59"
```

This is all documented in [the Regexp documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/regexp_rdoc.html).