# Return substring from map variable using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, orm

I have one variable that comes from a map, I'm trying to get a specific part between square brackets

> (e.g."dmfkdmfk[IWANTTHISPART]mlkm")

but it isn't  working by the way I did. I'm trying as same way used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661478/how-to-return-the-substring-of-a-string-between-two-strings-in-ruby).

Original Code:

```
query_values = activities.map do |activity|
  '(' +
  "#{activity['note']}"
  +')'

end
```

I tried:

```
query_values = activities.map do |activity|
  '(' +
  "#{activity['note'].[/#{"["}(.*?)#{"]"}/m, 1]}" 
  +')'

end
```

Error log:

```
syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting '('
      '(' + "#{activity['note'].[/#{"["}(.*?)#{"]"}/m, 1]},""'" +')'
                                 ^
quase.rb:40: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting tSTRING_DEND
```

How can I go through?
Many Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what relevance the "Original Code" has to the question.  Is that also non-working code that you tried?  Keep n mind that we're not supposed to have to follow any links to understand the question, if there is additional information in the link that would clarify the question, it's best to edit that information into the question itself.

Comment: @WayneConrad Original code is the one working but not implemented the question issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
str = "(dmfkdmfk[IWANTTHISPART]mlkm)"
```

**#1 Use a regex with lookarounds**

```
R0 = /
     (?<=\[) # match a left bracket in a positive lookbehind
     .+      # match one or more of any character
     (?=\])  # match a right bracket in a positive lookahead
     /x      # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

(same as  `R0 = /(?<=\[).+(?=\])/`)

```
str[R0] #=> "IWANTTHISPART"
```

**#2 Split string on a left or right bracket**

```
R1 = /
     [\[\]] # match a left or right bracket
     /x
```

(same as `R1 = /[\[\]]/`)

```
str.split(R1)[1]
  #=> "IWANTTHISPART"
```

**#3 No regex**

```
str[str.index('[')+1..str.index(']')-1]
  #=> "IWANTTHISPART"
```

Comment: Could also use `scan` here to find all instances of things inside square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a period after the receiver when using `[]` in its syntax-sugar form. The following is ungrammatical:

```
string.[regex, parameter]
```

Use either the ordinary method invocation form:

```
string.[](regex, parameter)
```

or the syntax-sugar form:

```
string[regex, parameter]
```

Comment: But how can I use this? I'm not sure how to use the regex.

Comment: @JulinhodaAdelaide You already have a regex. Aren't you trying to use that? The parameter can follow the regex.

Comment: Does it work with map variable? I tried it all way but no success. Can you help me?

Comment: `"#{activity['note'][/#{"["}(.*?)#{"]"}/m, 1]}"`

Answer (score 1):

```
/\[(.*)\]/.match( "dmfkdmfk[IWANTTHISPART]mlkm" )[1]
=> "IWANTTHISPART"
```

Comment: Should I use like : ""'  /\[(.*)\]/.match( #{activity['type']} )[1]""' 
??

Comment: @JulinhodaAdelaide, learn by trying! Your Rails console or IRB can answer that as fast as you can type it.

Comment: @JulinhodaAdelaide There's also [Rubular](http://rubular.com) which is handy for debugging regular expressions.

Comment: Good answer. A variant (which I don't like as well) is `("dmfkdmfk[IWANTTHISPART]mlkm" =~ /\[(.*)\]/) && $1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) with a regular expression:

```
> a = "dmfkdmfk[IWANTTHISPART]mlkm"
> a[/\[.*?\]/][1..-2]
#=> "IWANTTHISPART"
```