# Regexp to Get Content Between Two Markdown Headers / Sections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I am trying to get the content between two markdown headers, with the second delimiting header being optional. I would like the regexp to be able to support all types of headers e.g.

```
### Thing

# Thing #

Thing
=====
```

Based off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661478/how-to-return-the-substring-of-a-string-between-two-strings-in-ruby) this is what I have so far (assuming I want to get all content for header titled 'Stuff'):

```
^\s*#*\s*Stuff.*\n([\W\w]*?)(?:^\s*#*\s*\w+.*\n(?:\s*[-=]*\s*\n)?|\z)
```

but the capture group is returning an empty string ([link](https://regex101.com/r/pm4weq/5)). The solution should be able to return 'my content' for the following cases:

```
## Stuff
my content
```

2

```
# Stuff #
my content
```

3

```
# Thing
texty text

#Stuff
my content

# Other thing
```

4

```
Stuff
====
my content
```

If there are extra new lines or spaces in the result that's fine. This is assuming that there are no sub-headers in the content I want to get.

Comment: Maybe try https://regex101.com/r/pm4weq/6. Basically you're matching but not capturing groups with `(?: ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue in your regex is that the "next title detector" (`(?:^\s*#*\s*\w+.*\n(?:\s*[-=]*\s*\n)?|\z)`) will match ``! So it matches the first empty string right after your title (since the group capture is non-greedy) and leaves your capture empty. The second issue is that you only match titles starting by "Stuff" of the form 
`# Stuff`, not the pattern

```
Stuff
=====
```

And lastly, since you capture the next header, you can't correctly handly successive "Stuff" headers.

Here's a proposal to fix your regex:
`^(?<header>\s*#+\s*Stuff.*|\s*Stuff.*\n\s*(?:-{2,}|={2,}))\n(?<content>[\W\w]*?)(?=^(?:\s*#+|.*\n\s*(?:-{2,}|={2,}\s*\n))|\z)`
Be careful that Ruby is not exactly PCRE, so it's more accurate to make [tests on Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/Tmki51FgtM), though it's less user-friendly than [tests on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pm4weq/7)

Comment: Note: I made "header" and "content" groups for clarity, but you may want to remove the names (and make "header" non-capturing) to get your original behaviour back.

Comment: Fantastic answer! Thanks a lot for showing me where I went wrong, the tip about using Rubular, and your great solution. Learned some new things about regex from your post that will come in handy in the future.